# run zephir build error on tutorial

Tags: zephir

I installed zephir OK (0.3.7a) and run the test, and got error as follows:

> [root@vmlinux64 test]# zephir build PHP Warning:  system() has been
>   disabled for security reasons in
>   /usr/local/lib64/zephir/Library/CompilerFile.php on line 107 PHP
>   Warning: 
>   file_get_contents(.temp/0.3.7a/_root_test_test_Hello.zep.js): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /usr/local/lib64/zephir/Library/CompilerFile.php on line 110
>   Zephir\Exception: Cannot parse file: /root/test/test/Hello.zep

I run `zephir help` is ok. 0.3.7a .
and I do like this:

```
$ zephir test
$ cd test/test/
$ vim Hello.zep
```

**in `Hello.zep`:**

```
namespace Test;

class Hello
{
public function say()
{
echo "hello from test";
}
}
```

and save it, then go to `../` and run `zephir build`

the errors popped as above ...

I installed lnmp-1.0-full on my centOS6.5_x86_64, php version is 5.3.17.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I kinda had some issues too, and what I ended up doing was starting over from scratch and using the following code.

```
$ zephir init test
$ cd test/test/
$ vim hello.zep
```

Edit the file as necessary (I learned that you just keep the files and whatnot lowercase or Zephir blows up for some reason).

Then when you build, it should be fine.

As for your main issue, make sure you're running php 5.4 and above. I was running 5.3 and I ran into a bunch of problems until I upgraded my php version and then the problems magically went away.